# How to create a .tar.gz source archive in netbeans c++

Tags: makefile, netbeans

I wish to be able to redistribute the source for my netbeans project, preferably in a .tar.gz source archive. Currently if I just copy the source files, the makefile, and the relevant mk files from nbproject, it doesn't work. When I try and compile on another machine, make will complain that it can't find the source code, as the makefile tries to compile /home/user/netbeansprojecs/project/sourcefile, instead of the source files in the same folder as it.

Comment: can you please post your make file?

Comment: @OriginalCliche https://github.com/handuel/DifferenceEngine/blob/master/Makefile

Comment: @w4etwetewtwet Were you ever successful on solving your problem?